# How to blur a video efficiently on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video-streaming, webrtc

I am using CSS3 to blur some video that will be used on mobile browsers. My initial idea is to add a `.blur` class into `video` tag and my `.blur` CSS looks like:

```
.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(125px);
    -moz-filter: blur(125px);
    -o-filter: blur(125px);
    -ms-filter: blur(125px);
    filter: blur(125px);
}
```

I then found out when this blur class working on mobile browsers, it became EXTREMELY slow and lagged...

Are there any better ways to blur a video on mobile browsers? Either use JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this would definitely work, you can give it a try. Keep drawing the video on a canvas apply blur on the canvas.

to improve performance, you could:

- reduce the frame rate of the drawing onto the canvas
- IMO, `125px` is quite a high value, can try reducing it if your user case allows
- Instead of using css blur, you can write your own blur algorithm, [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) would give you the image data array, which you can manipulate. I am not sure how much you can optimize Gaussian blur, but pixelization might be a cheaper process( your image ll appear as blocks instead of being smooth).

```js
'use strict';

let video = document.createElement('video')
 ,  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
 ,  div = document.querySelector('#log')
 ,  frameRate = 10
 ,  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
 ,  log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
 
 video.autoplay = true;
 
 document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true})
        .then(stream => {
                  video.srcObject = stream; 
                  setInterval(draw, 1000/frameRate);
              }).catch(log);

function draw(){
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight; 
  canvas.width= video.videoWidth; 
 ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<button >Start</button>
<canvas></canvas>
<div id='log'></div>
```

Same code [in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mido22/bxxywym1/) to run on chrome.